# php include function leaves my page blank

Tags: php, include

When I try to include a php menu and/or footer onto my page, the whole page just shows up blank. But if I take the same code and put it back into the index.php html it works just fine. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the index page:

```
<div id="navigation">
<?php include 'menu.php'; ?>
        </div>
    <div id="content">
<?php
    echo "Hello World!";
?>
</div>
    <div id="footer">
    <?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
    </div>
```

ok and here's the menu.php and footer.php pages:
menu:

```
<?php
echo "<ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">main</a></li>
    <li><a href="info.php">php info</a></li>
    <li><a href="wda1.php">Assignment 1</a></li>
    </ul>";
    ?>
```

footer:

```
<?php
    echo "$filename = 'index.php';
        if (file_exists($filename)) {
        echo "This page was last modified: " . date ("F d, Y H:i:s.", filemtime($filename));
}";
        ?>
```

The tutorial at http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp would lead me to believe that I'm doing this correctly, but that apparently is not the case. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: 1. The syntax highlighter shows your error. 2. Turn on error reporting 3. Opinion: You should not use or link to [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com). It's not a reliable source of information and we don't want to encourage its use.

Comment: Think => q-u-o-t-e-s // look at them vary carefully in your menu.php file. Double quotes inside double quotes.

Comment: The fact that you get a white screen with all of these syntax errors means you have error_reporting and display_errors turned OFF. They should **NEVER** be off, especially while developing. If they'd been on, you'd have been informed of the errors.

Comment: I'm sure you got this error message =>>> `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'index' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in...` am I right? *Of course*

Comment: *Here,* I'll solve part of your problem then. Change `echo "<ul>` to `echo '<ul>` and `</ul>";` to `</ul>';` that'll fix your parse error. *Gee, I'm no nice.* --- I'll let you figure out your footer file now.

Comment: Ok on the menu section I fixed it by using \" by all the quotes, but that method didn't work so well on the footer section. I got it to display, but it displays the code itself and not the output of the code.

Comment: Yes, you could escape the double quotes, but that's just more work for nothing. Plus don't echo `echo "$filename = 'index.php';`

Comment: You forgot a double quote

Comment: Actually @AlexW There's a double quote too many, which should read as `echo $filename = 'index.php';` that's if the OP wants to echo the filename followed by `This page was last modified...`

Comment: Yeah I can't figure out the footer at all. If I include everything in quotes it displays code without the desired output (which is the last modified date and time) and if I take it out of quotes it's blank.

Comment: You have more problem with your footer code. Here: `echo $filename = 'index.php'; if (file_exists($filename)) { echo "This page was last modified: " . date ("F d, Y H:i:s.", filemtime($filename));};` that'll fix it. I should put in an answer instead with all the fixes I gave you to solve the problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

First file: (`index.php` I presume?)

```
<div id="navigation">
<?php include 'menu.php'; ?>
        </div>
    <div id="content">
<?php
    echo "Hello World!";
?>
</div>
    <div id="footer">
    <?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
    </div>
```

Menu:

```
<?php
echo '<ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">main</a></li>
    <li><a href="info.php">php info</a></li>
    <li><a href="wda1.php">Assignment 1</a></li>
    </ul>';
    ?>
```

Footer:

```
<?php

echo $filename = 'index.php';

  if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "This page was last modified: " . date ("F d, Y H:i:s.", filemtime($filename));
}

// else not required but will show nothing if file doesn't exit
// you can remove it, it's optional
else{
echo "<br>This is not index.php. But will still show the filename above this.";
}

?>
```

---

Here is a summary of the mistakes made:

1) `echo "<ul><li><a href="index.php">main</a></li>`

- You either escape the double quotes `\"` for your hyperlinks, or just wrap your echo using single quotes as shown in my answer above; it's a lot less work.

then:

2) `echo "$filename = 'index.php'; ... }";`

- You're wrapping that entire code in double quotes, hoping it will do just that; echo. This will generate a parse error, which is almost a carbon copy of what you did in point **#1**.
- Removing the first double quote before `$filename` then getting rid of the last one `}";`

---

***Troubleshooting tip(s)***

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` this will signal any errors found in your code and guide you along.

For more information on error reporting, visit PHP.net:

- **http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php**